# How to return correct enum when checkbox is added to a messagebox

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have created a messagebox which returns DialogResult. Now I added checkbox on it and want to know if it is checked or not. So what should I return? The simple way I thought is to create new enum which will have all the values from DialogResult plus a value to indicate checkbox status

```
public enum MyDlgResult
{
    NONE = DialogResult.NONE, 
    OK = DialogResult.OK ........................, 
    CHKBOXCHECKED = 8
}
```

...and returning this enum MyDlgResult. 
But is this correct approach? Because I have to add value in this enum every time a new functionality is added to my messagebox.
Better way to do this if any. 
Thank You.

Comment: You could use one enum for your checkboxes. The DialogResult enum is [redundant](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.dialogresult.aspx).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add Property to that message box, which will be a proxy to Checked property of CheckBox and on OK result form message box check that new Property.

Property to add

```
public bool Checked
{
   get { return yourCheckBox.Checked; }
}
```

And final code like this

```
MessBox box = new MessBox();
if(box.Show() == DialogResult.OK)
{
   bool isChecked = box.Checked;
}
```

Comment: Yes. This solves my problem to an extent. However I do not create instance of MessBox from UI. Just to get a good effect, from UI, suppose on a button click, I call 
`MessBox.Show()` 
and in my class **MessBox** i have written this **Show** method which creates instance  and returns **DialogResult** like
`return new MessBox().ShowDialog();`
So in this case I have to write this code in **MessBox.Show()** 
so how will I pass this value to UI ?? Thank You :)

Comment: Ok. I did this by setting another property in **MessBox** class and accessing it from UI. Please suggest if this is wrong approach. 
Thank You :)

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to override the return of a dialog to enable the client code to get the state of a UI control. The dialog information is retained after it is closed and you can get values from it. For example, assume that there is a Form class named SomeDlg with a property called PublicDlgProperty. PublicDlgProperty can be set on OK, or any other UI change and then queried after the dialog is closed, like this:

```
var someDlg = new SomeDlg();
someDlg.ShowDialog();

var someLocalVariable = someDlg.PublicDlgProperty;
```

This is a very simple example. You'll need to test the DialogResult to see if you want to query the value or not.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with both other people who answered you that you should have a property, delegating the IsChecked or something, but if you must do it using only the return enum result...

Make the enum Flagged:

```
[Flags]
public enum MyDlgResult
{
    NONE = ...
    OK = ...
    CHK...
}
```

Then, you can return:

```
return MyDlgResult.NONE | MyDlgResult.CHK;
```

Or

```
return MyDlgResult.OK | MyDlgResult.CHK;
```

Or just

```
return MyDlgResult.OK;
```

And so on...
Then, you can check:

```
if (res.HasFlag(MyDlgResult.OK))
{
}

if (res.HasFlag(MyDlgResult.CHK))
{
}
```